# ListView Control with paging capabilities

Tags: mfc

I am looking for a control similar to the one used in FeedDemon 2.7. it's a ListView with paging capabilities. it divides contents into pages. at the bottom of the control, you can see Page 1 of 3 and so on. you can see what I mean at the bottom of the attached picture : Page 1 of 3 .

I hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks.[alt text http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/133/listview.jpg](http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/133/listview.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the "pager" at the bottom of the screen is a different control than the list itself...

Have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/controls_pager.aspx) for a starting point. HTH